# React Native Share Image via Whats App and Facebook

Tags: react-native, share

I am trying to download an image from url then share it via whats app and other social media as an image format, I tried some method but I couldn't, my code is as follow:

```
let filePath = null;
        const configOptions = {
            fileCache: true,
        };
        RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions)
            .fetch('GET', url)
            .then(async resp => {
                filePath = resp.path();
                let options = {
                    url: filePath 
                };
                await Share.open(options);
                await RNFS.unlink(filePath);
            });
```

I tried also

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch("GET",url,{
                    Authorization : 'Bearer access-token...',
                  })
                .then(resp => {
                    console.log(resp)
                  let shareImageBase64 = {
                    title: "React Native",
                    message: "Hola mundo",
                    url: `data:image/png;base64,` + resp.base64(),

                  };
                  Share.open(shareImageBase64);
                })
```

it does open the share option but there is no image, only the message can be shared.

Comment: share single/multiple images or pdf file using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open issue in [github](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/280), the issue is only on IOS when sharing with whats app. The problem is that the message under shareImageBase64 overrides the url and you are sharing the message only, a workaround is to remove the message and you will be able to share your image successfully.